# Prove that either $a_n \to \infty $ or $a_n\to -\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let f be continuous and nonzero on R let $a_0$ be arbitrary and define $(a_n)$ recursively by $$a_n=a_{n-1}+f(a_{n-1}), n\ge 1$$ than either $a_n \to \infty $ or $a_n\to -\infty$,

Here
$a_n=a_{n-1}+f(a_{n-1})$

$a_n=a_{n-2}+f(a_{n-2})+f(a_{n-1})$

$a_n=a_{n-3}+f(a_{n-3})+f(a_{n-2})+f(a_{n-1})$

.............
.........

$a_n=a_{0}+f(a_0)+\cdots +f(a_{n-3})+f(a_{n-2})+f(a_{n-1})$

any help from here: thanks

Comment: This is easily not true. Pick a function $f$ so that $f(1) = -2$ and $f(-1) = 2$, e.g. $f(x) = -2x$, and choose $a_0 = 1$. Then $a_n$ oscillates between $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: @TheoBendit..... here $n \ge 1$ how did you take negative values

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. The question body states that the sequence begins at arbitrary $a_0$, and indeed we need an $a_0$ in order for the recurrence relation to work for $n = 1$. As for taking negative values, it was simply how I defined $f$. Is there some other additional restriction on $f$?

Comment: @TheoBendit I understand now but im not sure..and thank you

Comment: You're welcome! I commented rather than answered because I thought there must be some missing assumptions from the question. Where did you find it? Are you sure you copied over all the details?

Comment: @Theo: A continuous nonzero function cannot take both positive and negative values.

Comment: @MartinR Is that how you read it? I read it as a function that is not equal to the $0$ function.

Comment: Yes, I understand “a nonzero function” as a function which does not take the value zero. (And with that interpretation the statement is correct and easily provable.)

Comment: $f$ is either positive everywhere, or negative everywhere. In the first case the sequence $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing, in the second case the sequence is strictly decreasing. Does that ring a bell?